# In SAP UI5 `List` the "count-indicator" [ item-N / total-M ] is missing below the "More" button

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I'm developing software for 40+ years but I'm absolutely new to SAP UI5, so maybe this is very basic or a trivial problem but half a day of searching the internet brought no results:

In a Master-Detail View (defined in xml) I want to display a list of items with `growing=true`, `growingThreshold=50` and `growingScrollToLoad=false` as a `List`.

In principle it got everything working OK now. But there is a tiny glitch, not essential, more in the category of a "nice to have":

All the examples I've seen so far show something like "[ 50 / 107 ]" below the "More" button. **But in my program it is missing.** I'm very sure the reason is `__count` is not included in the response sent from the Odata-Service implementation.

Testing directly with the SAP Gateway Service Builder (/SEGW) shows to include the count in the response `$inlinecount=allpages` needs to be appended to the service URI. And here it works fine - once I add this to the URI the count is included, when I leave it out or set it to `none` there is no count included.

**Therefore the problem seems not to be in the service implementation.** (At least the `__count` field is present or not present as expected. And I assume this is what enables the "[ # / # ]" indicator.)

When the request is then sent from the controller (implemented in JavaScript) this part is **not** added to the service URI, despite the OData-Model is created with `defaultCountMode: "sap.ui.model.odata.CountMode.InlineRepeat"`. On the "Network" page of Chrome's developer tools I don't see the `$inlinecount=allpages` appended and also the "[ 50 / 107 ]" (or whatever is appropriate) is not shown with the "More" button.

I checked with the Chrome developer tools immediately after creating the Odata-Model if my setting in the OData-Model takes effect – and it does. And I checked once more before a request is made based on this OData-Model – and it is still there.

My only idea now is it might have something to do with the fact the request originates from the XML-view (ie. the JavaScript code created on behalf of it) and it might be using a different Odata model in which that option is not set.

How can I test for this?

Any other ideas?

Maybe an internationalization issue? (The trigger-text for displaying more entries is set to "Weiter" in German language. Maybe also the "[ # / # ]" parts needs to be re-defined elsewhere too?

Comment: Try with `defaultCountMode: "InlineRepeat"` instead of adding a fully qualified name in string. Otherwise, an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question would help us finding the issue faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the [comment of Boghyon Hoffmann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996801/in-sap-ui5-list-the-count-indicator-item-n-total-m-is-missing-below-th#comment113169191_63996801) solved the problem:

> [Use] `defaultCountMode: "InlineRepeat"` instead of adding a fully qualified name in string.